# is it okay to use loadOverlay() in a restartless addon?

Tags: dom, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-restartless

Firefox addon. I'm porting an existing addon to a restartless one. I have a panel with a lot of UI elements (mostly boxes/description and images) in it, and it is very convenient for me to define the panel elements in an XUL overlay file. I will have lots of bloated js code if I don't.

The panel element (parent) itself is created in code dynamically, and then I use `loadOverlay`, wait for the 'merged' event and then append the panel element's children from the overlayed document. I also make sure that the elements are cleaned up upon a remove.

However, using overlays will most probably won't pass an AMO review. And some of the reasons I think are :

- In most cases overlay elements will cause problems while removing (eg: toolbar buttons remembering their positions etc.)
- There are problems with attaching js/css files in an overlay file.
- loadOverlay is buggy ([496320](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=496320), [330458](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=330458))

And here are my inferences :

- loadOverlay() API itself is not deprecated - in fact it is '[not frozen and may change later](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.loadOverlay)' - which means possibly it will be use-able in future.
- The bug that a second overlay load fails, is not applicable in my case, as I don't initialize without an overlay merge.
- Using static overlay for preference windows etc. is perfectly acceptable as of now.
- The panel in my case behaves a lot like a preference window (which is brought up on demand and cleaned up upon addon removal)
- I don't have any js/css attached to the overlay, nor any event listeners for the elements. The overlay is only used to define boxes and description text - nothing more.

So considering these, is it acceptable to use overlays and loadOverlay() for a restartless addon ? If not, is there an alternative ?

Comment: This is good info about `loadOverlay` I hope someone helps you out, its not really my expertise.

Answer (score 0):

About overlays, by checking source code of restartless addon that extend existing addon (like [ehh](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/)), I see the overlay.xul is auto merged with the existing addon's. So it shouldn't be a problem to use overlay.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Using overlays are allowed for preferences windows etc. Also I believe they're are okay too as long as they are cleaned up 'properly' in a restartless way. But they're not generally recommended from the response I got from #amo-editors and #extdev channels. Especially `loadOverlay` is not recommended due to bugs. I ended up rewriting the whole UI in js. I really wanted to know if there were any alternatives than writing entire UI in js.